# Warnings when generating dSYM from AgoraRTCSDK

Tags: agora.io, xcode11.4

```
Showing All Messages
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/matthew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Open-dgeabqmaqhjdskgqxyigiofipvpc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Open.app.dSYM /Users/matthew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Open-dgeabqmaqhjdskgqxyigiofipvpc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Open.app/Open (in target 'Open' from project 'Open')
    cd /Users/matthew/open/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/matthew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Open-dgeabqmaqhjdskgqxyigiofipvpc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Open.app/Open -o /Users/matthew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Open-dgeabqmaqhjdskgqxyigiofipvpc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Open.app.dSYM

warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/agora_service_impl.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ap_client.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ap_manager.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ap_request.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ap_selector.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/api_reporter.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/api_tracer.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/async_rtc_event_handler.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/audio_device_manager.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/base_context.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/cache_file_manager.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/cache_manager.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/channel_info_collection.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/config_service.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/cross_channel_manager.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/log_uploader.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/media_engine_impl.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/network_monitor.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/proxy_client.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/proxy_manager.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/rtc_channel_event_handler_cpp_impl.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/rtc_code_mapper.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/rtc_context.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/rtc_engine_impl.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/rtc_engine_parameters_helper.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/rtc_notification.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/stream_rtc_event_handler.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/time_consumption_reporter.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/user_account_client.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/user_account_collection.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/video_device_manager.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/video_encoder_profile.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/video_profile.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/worker_manager_channel.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/worker_manager_packer.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/worker_manager_selector.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/rtm_async_event_handler.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/rtm_notification.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/rtm_service_impl.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/rtm_stream_event_handler.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AgoraConstants.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AgoraLiveKit.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AgoraLivePublisher.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AgoraLiveSubscriber.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AgoraMediaMetadataObserver.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AgoraObjects.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AgoraRtcEngineKit.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AgoraRtcEngineKitEx.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/rtc_bridge_impl.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/video_capturer_impl.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/core_service/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_sdk.build/Objects-normal/arm64/video_render_impl.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(CityHash.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(Reachability.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(cJSON.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(dns_parser.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(event_dns_parser.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(event_engine.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(event_http_client.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(event_http_client2.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(event_tcp_client.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(event_udp_server.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(file_header.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(file_manager.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(http_multipart_helper.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(json_wrapper.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(log.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(ping_client.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(ping_client_libevent.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(port_allocator.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(stream_buffer.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(sys_compat_ios.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(sys_compat_net_ios.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(util.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcommon.a(zip.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libconfig_engine.a(config_engine.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libchat_engine.a(chat_engine.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libchat_engine.a(media_io_controller.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libargus.a(cache_items.pb-c.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libargus.a(counter.pb-c.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libargus.a(message.pb-c.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libargus.a(rtmsdk_report_items.pb-c.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libargus.a(vosdk_report_items.pb-c.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libargus.a(protobuf-c.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libargus.a(protobuf_wrapper.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libargus.a(report_lbs.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libargus.a(report_lbs_selector.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libargus.a(report_link_manager.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libargus.a(report_qos.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libargus.a(report_service.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libplugin_manager.a(plugin_encryption.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libplugin_manager.a(plugin_manager.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libnet_test.a(net_test_stat.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libnet_test.a(network_test_manager.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libnet_test.a(network_tester.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libnet_test.a(public_domain_tester.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libnet_test.a(voet_client.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libnet_test.a(voet_manager.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libnet_test.a(voet_tester.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/liblive_stream.a(inject_stream_manager.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/liblive_stream.a(live_stream_client.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/liblive_stream.a(live_stream_controller.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/liblive_stream.a(live_stream_manager.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/liblive_stream.a(live_stream_protocol.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/liblive_stream.a(live_stream_service.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/liblive_stream.a(publish_cdn_manager.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcall_engine.a(signaling_client.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcall_engine.a(signaling_controller2.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcall_engine.a(signaling_service2.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcall_engine.a(audio_dwlink_rexfer.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcall_engine.a(call_context.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcall_engine.a(call_manager.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcall_engine.a(call_reporter.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcall_engine.a(call_stat.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcall_engine.a(capability_client.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_sdk3/proj.cmake/build/ios/lib/Release/libcall_engine.a(capability_manager.o) unable to open object file: No such file or directory
warning: (arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-
```

Receiving about 700 warning when trying to generate a dSYM file from the AgoraRTC library. Not sure how to resolve. I'm building with XCode 11.4 Any help is appreciated.

My assumption is that this is an issue with the SDK and that the agora team needs to make some changes to their SDK. Is anyone else facing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I has same issue when build iOS release, and I used agora SDK to do screenSharing, and there are 700 waring reported from Agora SDK.

```
(arm64) /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/NativeSDK/Agora-Native-SDK-iOS-Release/media_engine/build/cmake_video/build/ios/video/media_engine/agora_media_engine.build/Release-iphoneos/media_engine.build/Objects-normal/arm64/chat_engine_parameter.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
```